# Fetch contacts having assigned projects more than 2 in report module

Tags: mysql, sugarcrm

How to fetch data of contacts who have 2 products?

Contacts Table

```
id   name
1    Jon Doe
```

Projects Table

```
id  Project_name
1   prod_a
2   prod_b
```

project_contacts table

```
id    contact_id   project_id
1     1            1
2     1            2
```

I want results of those contacts who have both `prod_a` and `prod_b`

How to query this in report module

```
select c.name 
from
Contacts c,
Projects p,
project_contacts pc
WHERE
c.id = pc.contact_id
and p.id = pc.project_id
and p.name = "prod_a"
and p.name = "prod_b"
```

I want result to be fetched

```
name   
--------
John Doe
John Doe
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to perform a `JOIN` among-st the tables and then `group by` like

```
select c.name 
from Contacts c
join project_contacts pc on c.id = pc.contact_id
join Projects p on o.id = pc.project_id
WHERE p.Project_name in ('prod_a','prod_b')
group by c.id
having count(distinct c.name) = 2;
```

Comment: sorry for the delayed reply can i achieve the result without using count.

Comment: @NarayanPadhi, unfortunately no, `count()` here is to make sure that you both both the product